# How to make Devise respond to both html and json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am overriding the Devise Registrations and Sessions controller to respond to both html and json

Code for Registration Controller :

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    @user = User.create(user_params)
    if @user.save


      render :json => {:state => {:code => 0}, :data => @user }
    else
      render :json => {:state => {:code => 1, :messages => @user.errors.full_messages} }
    end
  end

private

  def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
  end
end
```

Currently this Registrations controller is only responding to json request. How to make this controller respond to both json and html request ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [respond_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_to) block to respond to multiple format:

```
def create
  @user = User.create(user_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {
      @user.save ? (render @user) : (render :new)
    }
    format.json {
      @user.save ? (render :json => {:state => {:code => 0}, :data => @user }) : render (:json => {:state => {:code => 1, :messages => @user.errors.full_messages} })
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: when i use this code I run into error 
undefined method `user_url' for # <RegistrationsController:0x007fb021f75ac0>
and it is pointing to @user.save method ...
Can you help please

Comment: now it is giving 
Template is missing error 

Missing partial users/_user with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/lovish/Desktop/devisetest/app/views" * "/home/lovish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.5.2/app/views"

Comment: That's right. you have create a html template for the user as you want to support html format.
create file: `_user.html.erb` inside your `app/views` then it will work

Comment: also I need to put each render block inside a parentheses like (render @user) : (render :new ) otherwise it gives syntax error

Comment: and what if I want the user to be signed_in and redirected to the root_url after he signs up ..
how can i implement that ?

Comment: to do that, you need to add more logic to your controller. `Devise` provides with some nice helper methods to work with e.g. `user_signed_in?`, `current_user` etc. you could use those and implement your requirement.
Is the above code working as what you asked for in your question? i.e., render both `json` and `html`?

Comment: Sorry I am new to Rails and I am unable to figure out how to fall back to original devise functionality of signing in a user on sign_up and redirecting to home url

Comment: Well, being new to Rails is not a problem. You have to solve your problems one by one, step by step. I think, what you asked in this question: `How to make this controller respond to both json and html request`, which can be solved by my answer.
If you have any other question, then you can ask another question with the details of your requirements.

Comment: Yeah sure please take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059117/making-devise-respond-to-both-html-and-json?noredirect=1#comment52017395_32059117