# devise not working when request header contains accept with value image/*;q=0.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise in my ruby on rails application.
I am calling following endpoint from a laptop web browser

```
https://myaddress/users/sign_in
```

It works well, but when I hit the same endpoint in mobile device it sends the request with header accept as `Accept: image/*;q=0.8`
Now server responds with 406 not acceptable.  How can I force devise gems to accept request which may contain header accept with value `image/*;q=0.8`

Comment: what exactly is image/;q=0.8. And why r you sending these header information?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to respond to an endpoint requesting an *image*, but it seems to me that you're looking for [`respond_to`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_to). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32055085/how-to-make-devise-respond-to-both-html-and-json).

I'd guess you want to respond to "any". To support `image` MIME types, you can find an example [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html) (emphasis mine):

> If you need to use a MIME type which isn't supported by default, you
> can register your own handlers in config/initializers/mime_types.rb as
> follows.
>
> ```
> Mime::Type.register "image/jpg", :jpg
> ```
>
> respond_to also allows you to specify a common block for different
> formats by using any:
>
> ```
> def index   @people = Person.all
>
>  respond_to do |format|
>    format.html
>    format.any(:xml, :json) { render request.format.to_sym => @people }   end end
> ```
>
> In the example above, if the format is xml, it will render:
>
> ```
> render xml: @people
> ```
>
> Or if the format is json:
>
> ```
> render json: @people
> ```
>
> `any` can also be used with no arguments, in which case **it will be used
> for any format requested by the user**:
>
> ```
> respond_to do |format|   format.html   format.any { redirect_to
> support_path } end
> ```
>
> Formats can have different variants.